# OpenVPN connection established but IP remains the same?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have an ASUS RT-N66U router which I recently supports VPN functionality. I enabled the OpenVPN option on it and am able to connect to it from a different location using the OpenVPN GUI, but my IP is not changing which I assume means my traffic is not being routed through it.

I want to use a VPN for security reasons (so that all of my traffic on public WiFi networks is encrypted). What am I doing wrong and how do I get my traffic to go through the router?

I'm using a Windows 7 x64 machine.

Comment: Your internal IP? Or your IP [here](www.whatismyip.com)

Comment: The latter, although I actually just have been googling "my ip"  and it shows at the top.

Comment: Some screenshots of the router and your setup woulb be nice.